# Casting policies to avoid "pointer cannot be null in well-defined C++ code"

Tags: c++

Recent compilers, e.g. clang, complain if a function tests if "this" is NULL, as this is illegal according to the standard.

I have a program that made large use of this, and am trying to clean it up. Below are some examples that don't warn - are these safe or not?  Is there a good way to get the ->toAA and ->toAB functionality behaviour that is C++ standard compliant?  (Ideally without changing the code that is calling these functions, and reasonably fast - see the note below that testing this is faster in GCC 4.6.)

```
#include <stddef.h>

class ClassAA;
class ClassAB;

class ClassBase {
public:
  enum Type {AA, AB};
  Type m_type;
  ClassAA* toAA();
  ClassAB* toAB();
  ClassBase(Type t) : m_type(t) {}
  virtual ~ClassBase() {}
};
class ClassAA : public ClassBase { public: int a; ClassAA():ClassBase(AA) {} };
class ClassAB : public ClassBase { public: int b; ClassAB():ClassBase(AB) {} };

// toAA and toAB are intended to have same function,
// but toAB is significantly better performing on GCC 4.6.
inline ClassAA* ClassBase::toAA() { return dynamic_cast<ClassAA*>(this); }
inline ClassAB* ClassBase::toAB() { return (this && m_type == AB) ? static_cast<ClassAB*>(this) : NULL; }

int foo(ClassBase* bp) {
    if (bp && bp->toAA())   // Legal
    return -1;
    if (dynamic_cast<ClassAA*>(bp))   // Legal
    return -1;
    if (!bp->toAA())             // No warning, is this legal?
    return -1;
    if (bp->toAA()->a)     // No warning, is this legal?
    return 10;
    if (bp->toAB()->b)     // Warning due to use of "this", illagal presumably
    return 20;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use `return m_type == AB ? ...`

Comment: Inside `toAB` you check for `this`. Makes no sense as this should be called from a legal `this` in the first place.

Comment: toAB is intended to work like dynamic cast - if passed a NULL it must return NULL. This is why it checks "this".

Answer (score 1):

Make them free functions instead, or `static` members that take an argument.

Non-static member functions must be invoked on an extant object; period.

Your compiler isn't warning likely because you don't dereference `this`, so its detection algorithm isn't triggered. But that doesn't make the behaviour any less undefined. The compiler could be omitting the warning then sneaking off to make pancakes, for all you know.